# Is ADD_ONION control command implemented in the latest stable release?

Tags: configuration, protocol, network-configuration

[control-spec.txt](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) mentions an `ADD_ONION` command to create ephemeral hidden services. Does this exist in the latest stable release of Tor or Tor Browser Bundle?

Comment: a long time ago, by the way - take a look at their stable branch

Answer (score 1):

According to the line 1405 from control-spec.txt, it's present since Tor 0.2.7.1-alpha. Current Tor Browser Bundle (version 5.0.6) use Tor 0.2.7.6, which is a stable one. ADD_ONION should be implemented.